# What is the purpose of NSKeyValueChangeSetting

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing

In my `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` method I have a switch with these cases:

```
case NSKeyValueChangeReplacement: /* replace an existing row */
case NSKeyValueChangeInsertion: /* insert a new row */
case NSKeyValueChangeRemoval: /* remove an existing row */
```

So far so good.

I also have to deal with `NSKeyValueChangeSetting`, but I dunno what to code.

```
case NSKeyValueChangeSetting: /* what about this one? */
```

So what is its purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002299-SW11):

> Indicates that the value of the observed key path was set to a new value. This change can occur when observing an attribute of an object, as well as properties that specify to-one and to-many relationships.

Basically this is a plain old "value changed for key"-style "notification", so to say.

Comment: Yes I have read the docs. How is this different from NSKeyValueChangeReplacement?

Comment: @neoneye in this case, the value need not correspond to a to-many relationship.

Comment: I don't get it. Would NSKeyValueChangeSetting be used with NSMutableString. And NSKeyValueChangeReplacement be used with NSMutableArray. Is it like this?

Comment: @neoneye What I deduce from the wording of the docs, something like this.

Comment: Just wondering if I need to implement the NSKeyValueChangeSetting. I have my own homebaked mutable-ordered-set (a to-many relationship).

Comment: @neoneye I think you better implement it (similarly to how you implement `NSKeyValueChangeReplacement `).

Comment: I have an NSArray-based property that has an associated clear command. This would change the array to an empty NSArray. So instead of using `NSKeyValueChangeRemoval` with every index, I could use `NSKeyValueChangeSetting` to express that I splattered the old value wholesale?

Comment: Actually typing in the code, I don't got that right. You don't directly specify `NSKeyValueChangeSetting`. If you change a container with the general non-container will/did-change pair, this is what change-type you'll get.